# Escape a character knowing only its index

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm looking to escape a `\n` character knowing only its index. I am NOT looking to replace the character itself, but rather "prepend" an escape character to the existing `\n`, effectively escaping it.

For example, in JavaScript: `'\\' + '\n' === '\\\n'`

What I'm looking for is `\\n` not `\\\n`.

To reiterate, I do NOT want to replace `\n` entirely. I am well aware `'\n'.replace('\n', '\\n')` would do what I'm looking for. I simply want to prepend an escape character to the existing newline. Is there a reason that JS prepends a literal backslash and does not escape the newline?

`'\\' + '\'' === "\\'"`

I guess I'm wondering why the newlines behave differently. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to prepend a backslash to a character in order to escape it. For example, with a newline character, `'\n'`, to Javascript, this is a string containing one character code: 10.

```js
for (const char of '\n') {
  console.log(char.charCodeAt());
}
```

There is not actually an `n` (nor a literal backslash) anywhere in there - `\n` is simply the convention programmers use and understand to refer to a newline. If a string is composed of a literal backslash and a literal `n`, the character codes are completely different: there's a character code of 92 (for the backslash) and a character code of 110 (for the `n`).

```js
for (const char of '\\n') {
  console.log(char.charCodeAt());
}
```

Your only option is to completely replace the literal newline character with a backslash and an `n` (with `'\n'.replace('\n', '\\n')` - or, for a more general solution, construct a Map or object of literal characters and their escape sequences)